# NoOutputStreamException during image upload in vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin, image-uploading

Trying to upload only images. The problem is that I don't know how to handle this situation.

```
    @Override
    public OutputStream receiveUpload(String filename, String mimeType)  {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        if(mimeType.startsWith("image")) {
            picture = new Picture();
            picture.filename = filename;
            picture.mimeType = mimeType;

            picture = HibernateUtils.save(picture);
            product.pictures.add(picture);
            File dirs = new File(IMAGE_LOCATION);
            File file = new File(IMAGE_LOCATION + picture.id);
            if (!dirs.exists()) {
                dirs.mkdirs();
            }
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

        } else {
            Notification.show("", Notification.Type.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
       return fos;
    }
```

The problem is that the `fos` variable will be `null` if I try to upload different type of files than `image`. The question is that, how should I handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
...
} else {
    Notification.show("", Notification.Type.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    return new ByteArrayOutputStream();
}
...
```

Comment: I wrote fos = new NullOutputStream() and changed type of fos to OutputStream and it worked

Comment: So Krayo's solution writes the uploaded file to memory, and @chabeee 's solution discards it?

Comment: @golimar Yes (if the uploaded file is not image).